# passing multiline python command to maya commandPort

Tags: python, maya

i want to pass multiline python command as a string variable to maya commandPort in following format. But looks like it errors out , when executed in maya through port. It erros as Unterminated string. //

In maya , i have opened a command port as

import maya.cmds as cmds cmds.commandPort(name=":6001")

Here is the command i execute in nuke to pass to maya command port , when supplied multiline command in form code1 variable it doesnt work, but when we supply command in code2 , it works. Is there a way to pass long multiline command string without using \n or ; in the same line ?

```js
### multiline string like below doesn't work, errors as unterminated sring

code1="""
cmds.polySphere()
"""

### if supplied in below format ,it works
code2="cmds.polySphere()" 

import socket
host = 'localhost'
port = 6001

try:
   # Connect to Maya Command Port
   maya = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   maya.connect( (host,port) )
   # Send Command Through Socket --> Can Only Send MEL Commands
   message = 'python("{}")'.format(code1)
   print message
   maya.send(message)

except:
   raise Exception, 'Connection Failed To : %s:%s' % (host, port)

finally:
   # Close Socket Connection
   maya.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It executes properly if `code1` is formatted in a single line:

```
code1 = """cmds.polySphere()"""
```

And you can use a `;` (semi-colon) to run multiple commands:

```
code1 = """cmds.polySphere();cmds.polyCube()"""
```

I personally find it more readable to format it like this using `\n` (new line):

```
code1 = ("cmds.polySphere()\\n"
         "if 2 > 1:\\n"
         "    cmds.polyCube()")
```

The `\n` needs to be escaped with an extra `\` because it's being placed in another string in your `message` variable.

You can also use `replace()` to avoid escaping altogether:

```
code1 = ("cmds.polySphere()\n"
         "if 2 > 1:\n"
         "    cmds.polyCube()").replace("\n", "\\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply :)

I also found a way to write multiline the normal way without having to add \n or ; , and automate it in the next step

```js
code1_multiLine="""
                 for i in range(5):
                     print i
                """
code1_singleLine=code1_multiLine.replace("\n",r"\n")   

##then pass , this to the command port , in the top most example.

message = 'python("{}")'.format(code1_singleLine)
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you have a full example for this (maybe gist), that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**SourceType**:
Opening a default command port which takes **MEL** input, we don’t need to specify **Python** as source type, as we can just use python("[insert command here]") to wrap it into **MEL**, this can be blocks of independent codes or importing and executing python files.

**Mixed Quotation symbol**:
Note that when doing a source type conversion with a string type command , quotation symbol may cause conflicts. The solution is to replace it with backslash before quotation symbol.

`command = 'python("' + command.replace(r'"', r'\"') + '")'`

See full detailed example:

https://www.xingyulei.com/post/maya-commandport/